# How can i improve my random programm AHK Script

Tags: random, autohotkey

I am a beginner in programming. I need a program that generate a random number between 1 - 100 in each second.  This is the code I wrote with simple AHK Script.

```
Loop
{
 Random, rand_num, 1, 100
ToolTip, Random number:`n%rand_num%`n`nPress ESC to close
Sleep, 1000
}

ESC::ExitApp
```

The result is okay. But i think their are way better options to solve this task. the program don't run smooth. so when i move the mouse, the field with the number is lagging. or lagging is maybe the wrong word. it doesn't move real time with the mouse. and a second think is the => press escape to close text. is their a easy way to remove this? so that the field with the numbers gets a little bit smaller? 
i have some experience in java and python,maybe its easier to create a program with these languages. but i am beginner. hope someone can help me either with my AHK script or with tips how can i solve the task in another language. thanks for each helping comment

Comment: what is java doing in the tag list?

Comment: One does not simply want to display a random number. What is the use of this, do you need an UI ? Why java/python ?

Comment: i have some experience in java and python. so maybe when its easy to creatre a randomprogramm in these languages some1 can give me a startingpoint or some tipps. but im new here. so sry if the taggs are wrong. i didnt find a AHKScripttag.

Comment: I need this programm for a strategicgame. I have charts and i play a specific moves with a mixxed strategie. For example one move ill play 65% with move a and 35% with move b. So when i get each second a random number between 1 and 100 i can randomnize my game. my AHK script does the task. but its not the best solution avaible i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetBatchLines, -1
lastNumTick := A_TickCount
Random, randNum, 1, 100
SetTimer, UpdateRandomNumber, 1

UpdateRandomNumber:
    If (A_TickCount > lastNumTick+1000) {
        Random, randNum, 1, 100
        lastNumTick := A_TickCount
    }
    ToolTip, %randNum%
Return

ESC::ExitApp
```

Or maybe you prefer that:

```
SetTimer, UpdateRandomNumber, 1000

UpdateRandomNumber:
    Random, randNum, 1, 100
    TrayTip,, %randNum%
Return

ESC::ExitApp
```

Comment: The first one is just perfect and the second is also very nice. Thank you alot. Problem solved.

Comment: Great, you may click this check mark next to the answer then, to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 solution:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyRandom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int iRandomValue;

        while (true) {
            // random.nextInt(99) generates number between 0 and 99;
            iRandomValue = 1 + random.nextInt(99);
            System.out.println("Random number: " + iRandomValue);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException exIgnoreInterrupted) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```